# How to pass Contour URL parameters as combination of date range filter (startDate and endDate) and multiple value string filter

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop, foundry-contour

I have integrated contour graph in workshop module with iframe. i am using (node id and change id to select particular graph).Now i wanted to filter data from workshop which will be passed to contour graph using URL parameters.

There are two ways as per document -

1. /workspace/contour-app//ref//changeId/?embedded=true&useMostRecentNodeId=true&cityparamId=Manhattan (single value filter)
2. /workspace/contour-app//ref//changeId/?embedded=true&useMostRecentNodeId=true&cityparamId=Manhattan,Queens&**contour_multiple_values**=enabled (multiple value filter)

What i want to achieve is below url

workspace/contour-app//ref//changeId/?embedded=true&useMostRecentNodeId=true&startDateparamid=2024-01-01&endDateparamid=2024-02-01&cityparamId=Manhattan,Queens&**contour_multiple_values**=enabled

but when i use above URL it gives me blank page. Am i missing something here? How to combine date range parameters and string parameter with multiple values ?